# Which is the most seen play in Esperanto?

Tags: culture

I know there are plays shown during Universala Kongreso, for example. I'd like to know which one had the most viewers.

Comment: Would you count watching a recording of a play? Because the EAB sells a recording of _La Graveco de la Fideliĝo_ and I bet a lot of people have seen that.

Comment: A difficult question. Does the new film "Gerda malaperis" still count as play?
Speaking about local plays in theaters or at Esperanto arrangements I would suggest to find out 
* which players or theater groups actually exist
* how often they perform
* how often the actual play was performed and
* how many people took part in the arrangement
later do some statistical calculations and assumptions that lead to "La Kredito" by Jordi Galceran, played dum UK 2016 by Saŝa Pilipovic kaj Georgo Handzlik. (I liked it.)
"Which is the most sung song in Esperanto"? This question is way easier...

Comment: I remember that in the 100th esperanto congress were two plays, Felicxas Cxiuj and Viro-Semo, which seemed extremely appreciated (I couldn't attend the later, even coming half an hour before, thought I've tried three times in a row). They probably had a great number of viewers, considering the number of people who came to Lille this year. However I couldn't say if they had the most.

Comment: This might not be too helpful but you can look at the plays in on this site: http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Esperanto_(Bookshelf)

Answer (score 3):

The most seen play would probably be Gerda Malaperis since it is available on Youtube, which gives it a large reach.

In terms of a live theatre plays, it is hard to know because it is difficult to dig up records of attendance. But maybe this will help:

> A play written by Carmel Mallia in the international language Esperanto, entitled Najbaroj (Neighbours), won first prize in a drama competition held annually by the Universal Esperano Association. 
>   http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20120819/social/Esperanto-congress.433453